# How to reference singleton that gets destroyed in the scene

Tags: unity-game-engine, reference, singleton

Suppose I have an audio manager singleton (present in all scenes) and all scenes have a button to enable and disable audio.

Suppose I'm in the scene A and I go to scene B.

In scene B, the buttons that referenced the functions of the singleton lose their reference because the audio manager object is destroyed, because a previous audio manager comes from scene A and the one from scene B is destroyed (since there cannot be 2 of it).

Is there a smart way to solve this problem?

---

Of course I can create a class whose methods call singleton functions and let them in all scenes, but that doesn't seem smart.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of doing this is having an `Init()` function in your singleton. In the way you are describing it, this object is `DontDestroyOnLoad` as well. In the method of `Start` or `Awake` you'll find all other instances of this object and if another exists deleting the new one so the old one persists.

Inside of this function if another object is found, simply call a new `Init` function that takes all the references you need as parameters so the old Singleton gets all the information of the new one, then the new one is deleted.

```
public class myClass : MonoBehaviour 
{
     public static myClass i;
     [SerializeField] private Gameobject myReference = null;
     
     void Awake () 
     {
         if(!i) 
         {
             i = this;
             DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
         }
         else 
         {
             i.Init(myReference);
             Destroy(gameObject);
         }
     }

    public void Init(GameObject myNewRef)
    {
           myReference = myNewRef;
    }
    ...
```

Hope the snippet adds a bit more clarify.